# media queries for screen resolution of kiosk device

Tags: css

I am trying to create website in kiosk device. It is working fine when I test it in my browsers(chrome). But when it comes, to kiosk device, the page is fully distorted. The kiosk screen resolution is 1980 x 1020. Actually my page has two columns width 50% each. And each column has some fields arranged.Can somebody please guide me as how to start with the media queries for this resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made the website for smaller resolutions and then you will put kiosk resolution, the images and other elements are going to be bigger (so will be distorted).
You need to implement in your website different resolutions (thinking in different devices) and in this case you need to think in the big resolution that you can put your web, ie: Full HD and then resize to smaller resolutions.